# vba save excel worksheet with workbook name plus text as a PDF

Tags: excel, vba

This code only saves with the workbook name and not the text "Sample". What am I doing wrong? All answers appreciated
Thanks,
Ed

```
Sub SamplePDF()
Dim strFolder As String
    Dim i As Long

    'Find the position of the period in the file name
    i = InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")

    Filename = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, i - 1) & "Sample"
    Sheets("Sample").Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Quality _
        :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: You calculate `Filename` but use it nowhere. There is a parameter in `ExportAsFixedFormat` to specify the name, you just have to use it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat

Comment: You've omitted the Filename parameter. Surprised it didn't error tbh.

Comment: It's said as being optional

Comment: Ah yes fair enough, but why omit it if you want to give it a specific name? Just add it back in and remember to include the extension.

Comment: I agree it should be added :) was only saying it is not surprising that no errors occur :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling VBA the filename. Append `Filename:= Filename` (although I would change the variable name for better reading to, for example, `wbFilename`:

```
i = InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")

wbFilename = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, i - 1) & "Sample"
Sheets("Sample").Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Quality _
    :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True, Filename:=wbFilename
```

Comment: You should just record a macro to do what you want.  The Macro recorder can't record loops and it can't record 'logic' but it can record most of the items you click through.  You will learn a lot from reading the code that the Macro Recorder produces.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

For trace with the additional argument:

```
Filename = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, i - 1) & "Sample.pdf"
Sheets("Sample").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Quality _
    :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True, Filename:=FileName
```

Edit: @SJR mentioned your may need to add the extension in `Filename`
Also, I've condensed`Sheet("Sample").Select / ActiveSheet.` (which was probably incorrect anyway, I believe it should have been `Sheet("Sample").Activate`).

Comment: The variable name nor the order will be a problem.

Comment: I am learning stuff today. Sometimes Excel is fussy about that.

Comment: @SJR: As long as you type `Parameter:=Somevalue` it will be fine. If you want to omit the `Parameter:=` part of it, only then you need to type it in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for the help